# Replace each text match found by appending a count value - Regex (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

My text file is as below :

```
<number>Object</number>
<name>Object</name>
<number>Object</number>
<name>Object</name>
<number>Object</number>
<name>Object</name>
<number>Object</number>
<name>Object</name>
<number>Object</number>
<name>Object</name>
```

I want to append a count value to each subsequent text (`<number>Object</number>`) that is found.
**Output:**

```
<number>Object1</number>
<name>Object</name>
<number>Object2</number>
<name>Object</name>
<number>Object3</number>
<name>Object</name>
<number>Object4</number>
<name>Object</name>
<number>Object5</number>
<name>Object</name>
```

**Note:** Need to do this using Notepad++ or any other freeware Text editor.

Comment: regex cant count

Comment: @Fallenhero Any other thing apart from regex? The file content is huge, so I can't manually re-number it.

Comment: I dont know of any text editor that could do this. But this should be easy in any programming  language

Comment: Is there any possibilities you can use sublime text?

Answer (score 0):

A perl one-liner that does the job:

```
perl -ane 's~(?<=<number>Object)(?=</number>)~++$i~e;print' inputfile > outputfile
```